# How do I use the philsturgeon Codeigniter template?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am started to use the Codeigniter framework, and I want use Phil Sturgeon's Codeigniter template:

http://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template/zipball/master

I followed the installation steps like below :

1. Download the latest version
2. Copy the files from this package to the correspoding folder in your application folder

   - copy from `config/template` to corresponding place (in config directory.)
   - copy from `libraries/template` to corresponding place (in libraries directory.)
   - Loading Template ( writing `$this->load->library('template');` in `config/autoload.php`)

And at the end I use this template in controller like this:

```
public function index() {
  $data["header"] = "ayastr"; 
  $data["content"] = "content1"; 
  $this->template->enable_parser(TRUE);
  $this->template->enable_parser_body(TRUE); 
  //$this->template->set('title', "test");
  $this->template->title("aya"); 
  $this->template->build('example_page_view', $data);
 }
```

In the view `example_page_view.php`,I have `layouts\default.php`, I wrote

```
{{ template:title }}
```

.. in `default.php`.
but I can't access the title variable. What did I do wrong, or not do?
I add this section that I can use $template['title'] in `default.php` but i can't use parser for show my variables.

Comment: I've made considerable edits to your question, please view the [version history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15153889/revisions) to see how I used formatting, and follow that as a guide in the future.

Comment: thanks Tim for your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy Template.php file to libraries folder from the package you downloaded.
2. Copy template.php file to config folder
3. Have you templates under views/templates
4. Edit the template.php (config file) as below

   ```
   //Default Template Configuration (adjust this or create your own)
   //Default template - This is the Main template

   $template['default']['template'] = 'template/template';
   $template['default']['regions'] = array('menu','content','title');

   $template['default']['parser'] = 'parser';
   $template['default']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
   $template['default']['parse_template'] = TRUE;



   //Login Template
   $template['login']['template'] = 'template/template_login';
   $template['login']['regions'] = array('content');

   $template['login']['parser'] = 'parser';
   $template['login']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
   $template['login']['parse_template'] = TRUE;
   ```

This is the basic configuration, If you want more info on how to send data from views, let me know

Comment: Thanks MDeSilva , this answer is useful for who that can not install template. I can access to my variable with $template (for example `echo $template['title'];`) but i can not access with parser way. by a lot of thanks.